# Is there a way to make all Mosaico blocks the same width?

Tags: mosaico

When adding Mosaico blocks each has its own width.  That creates problems if you want a different color for the external background but not have it change its width  depending on the width of each Mosaico block.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Mosaico template 1.19 solves the problem with transparent background for the Logo block at the top.  Thanks